# importError: cannot import name opendocx

Tags: python, docx

I'm trying to make a txt file from docx using this code:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from docx import opendocx, getdocumenttext
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from cStringIO import StringIO

def convert_pdf_to_txt(path):
    ...

def document_to_text(filename, file_path):
    ...
    elif filename[-5:] == ".docx":
        document = opendocx(file_path)
        paratextlist = getdocumenttext(document)
        newparatextlist = []
        for paratext in paratextlist:
            newparatextlist.append(paratext.encode("utf-8"))
        return '\n\n'.join(newparatextlist)
    elif filename[-4:] == ".odt":
        ...
    elif filename[-4:] == ".pdf":
        ...

document_to_text('1.docx','D:\Nucho\Python\AntiPlagiat\1.docx')
```

However, I see only: `ImportError: cannot import name opendocx`

Some text '.......'  to post question.

Comment: Hi! Did you ever solve this issue? I'm suffering because of this right now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

pls read,
The 'opendocx()' function is no longer part of the latest version of python-docx. Starting with v0.3.0, python-docx has been completely re-written and the API is not backwardly compatible. The new call would be something like:

```
document = Document(docx_file_path)
```

Documentation on the new version is available here:
http://python-docx.readthedocs.org/

If you want the prior API, you should install `docx` rather than `python-docx`, e.g.:

```
pip install docx
```

The package name changed between the two versions, so folks can still access the legacy version if that's what they want. You should uninstall python-docx before installing docx, and vice versa, to avoid confusion over which is being imported.

Let me know if you need more.

ref:https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/python-docx/otp6hq4kJ5c/tfQB88Mfx2gJ